# Find button by its content

Tags: jquery, css

I have a page with several button element. I need a find a specific button which has content "Mail Me".

```
<div>
    <button class="h1">Submit</button>
    <button class="c1">Edit</button>
    <button class="c5">Mail Me</button>
    <button class="r4">Cancel</button>
</div>
```

I am searching for some CSS solution but didn't find. How can I do this with either CSS or jQuery?

Comment: Any chance you can set a class or id on the "Mail Me" button?  It will make this easier in CSS or JavaScript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [**:contains()**](https://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/)

```js
 $("button:contains('Mail Me')").css('color', 'green');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
    <button class="h1">Submit</button>
    <button class="c1">Edit</button>
    <button class="c5">Mail Me</button>
    <button class="r4">Cancel</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use filter function:

```
$('button').filter(function(){
  return $(this).text() == "Mail Me";
});
```

### Working Demo

Answer (score 1):

For your case there is no pure CSS solution.
Use Javascript for it, or change your buttons to:

```
<input type="button" value="Mail Me">
```

And use the following CSS selector:

```
button[value="Mail Me"] {}
```

See the [CSS documentation from w3.org](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#attribute-selectors)